# What is the proper type of UV rays for COVID-19 sterilization?

Tags: prevention, coronavirus, uv-rays, sterilization

I have seen [this device](https://spectrum.ieee.org/automaton/robotics/medical-robots/autonomous-robots-are-helping-kill-coronavirus-in-hospitals) which is used for medical sterilization:

[image]

I like to know **proper type of UV light** for **Covid-19**, and seen this posts:

> UV light covers a wavelength spectrum from 100 to 380 nm and is
>   subdivided into three regions by wavelength: UVA (320 to 400 nm), UVB
>   (280 to 320 nm), and UVC (200 to 280 nm) (1). Among them, UVC has the
>   strongest germicidal effect and is widely used in the form of mercury
>   lamps to inactivate microorganisms.[ [reference](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4702654/) ]
>
> But, on the other hand, there are a few sources that mention that UVC
>   is the most dangerous wavelength that can cause skin cancer. ... The
>   shorter-wavelength, higher-energy UV radiation associated with the UVC
>   category is very strongly absorbed by most organic materials.  [ [reference](https://hps.org/publicinformation/ate/q9450.html) ]

According these data i think the **UVC** Type is proper to be used at this devise, but i asked here for consideration more details like **standards** and **medical health consideration** for choosing the proper UV lamp Type.

Thanks.

Comment: My answer here addresses how much UVC is needed https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/21593/3414